# Get external referals per Facebook Tab

Tags: facebook, facebook-insights

Using facebook insights - is it possible to get an external referral by Tab and not by page?
The fql reference for insights (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/) mention that it is possible for canvas (application_canvas_views_external_referrals) but not for Tab, but I would assume this is a desirable feature.

Any advice would be appreciated. Surprisingly, I can't find any information on this issue.